# Installation question

Tags: dual-boot

I'm considering installing Ubuntu as a replacement for Windows 10.  I see a possibility to run ubuntu alongside W10 as a learning aid, and this is probably my favoured option.  If I do this, when I switch on my laptop, will it start both OS, just W10 or just ubuntu?  How do I switch between them or set a default OS for login?  Will my various files (e.g. pictures or music) and documents stored on W10 be available on ubuntu - are they copied automatically as part of the install?  If I decide to keep W10 can I uninstall ubuntu, and vice versa?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Ubuntu alongside Windows, you'll be able to select which OS to boot.

Your files will be available from Ubuntu. There is no need to copy them anywhere because Ubuntu can read NTFS partitions.

It is possible to remove Ubuntu. It is a bit harder than to install though.